# How to do a secure logout with Auth0 using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, access-token, auth0, appauth

I have followed this [article](https://auth0.com/blog/get-started-with-flutter-authentication/) on how to get started with using Auth0 in Flutter.

The author writes: "*...a complete secure logout is beyond the scope of this article*".

The logout method from the article is this:

```
void logoutAction() async {
await secureStorage.delete(key: 'refresh_token');
setState(() {
  isLoggedIn = false;
  isBusy = false;
});
```

}

I removes the refresh_token from secure storage on the device.
Now, I want to be able to do a more complete logout where that user will have to do a full login again with username and password. Currently, the user can log in without typing username and password which I think is due to the access token being saved somewhere. If, this is due to the access token, How can I delete this access token from browser cookies or wherever it is being stored?

One way to avoid storing the access token is to add `promptValues: ['login]` to the login method. The problem with this is that the user will have to login every time, therefore completely removing the benefits from the stored access token. So again, I want the user to be able to do a "complete" logout where the access token is cleared from cookies.

```
Future<void> loginAction() async {
setState(() {
  isBusy = true;
  errorMessage = '';
});

try {
  final AuthorizationTokenResponse result =
      await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
    AuthorizationTokenRequest(
      AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      AUTH0_REDIRECT_URI,
      issuer: 'https://$AUTH0_DOMAIN',
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access'],
      // promptValues: ['login']
    ),
  );

  final idToken = parseIdToken(result.idToken);
  final profile = await getUserDetails(result.accessToken);

  await secureStorage.write(
      key: 'refresh_token', value: result.refreshToken);

  setState(() {
    isBusy = false;
    isLoggedIn = true;
    name = idToken['name'];
    picture = profile['picture'];
  });
} catch (e, s) {
  print('login error: $e - stack: $s');

  setState(() {
    isBusy = false;
    isLoggedIn = false;
    errorMessage = e.toString();
  });
}
```

}

Comment: Did you find a way for this?

Comment: No not yet unfortunately

Comment: Auth0 has a logout url, but it doesn't seem to work... https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#logout

Answer (score 0):

just uncomment the line in method loginAction():

// promptValues: ['login']

Comment: This is not viable as I state in the answer "The problem with this is that the user will have to login every time, therefore completely removing the benefits from the stored access token."

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to analyse the logout function given in the article.

Previously Auth0 seemed to send a refresh token when calling

```
appAuth.token
```

but it's not the case anymore, so i commented the following code

```
await secureStorage.write(6
      key: 'refresh_token', value:response.refreshtoken);
```

now if the user is logged in, the flutter app has the refresh token available to call appAuth.token, if he's logged out the token was deleted.